# How to run single command on multiple files to convert file format?

Tags: conversion

I am trying to convert file format from `fa` to `fq` using `seqkit` on Linux terminal. Command is simple as shown below.

```
seqkit fq2fa Std_metabat2_bin.9_sub.fa -o Std_metabat2_bin.9_sub.fq -j 20
```

But, I have over 200 files (`fa` file of metagenome bins) and am wondering if there is better way than converting one file at one time.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use a `for` loop to convert all the `.fa` files in the directory:

```
for file in *.fa; do seqkit fq2fa "$file" -o $(basename "$file" .fa).fq -j 20; done
```